# Python Pip Permissions

Tags: apt, permissions, python, bashrc, virtualenvwrapper

I deleted Python on 14.04, **woops**! It was 4am and I can't remember why I was doing this. So I re-installed it and all and it works, except for some of that good old virtualenvwrapper.

I've searched all over the internet to figure out what's wrong, I have the correct owners on `~/.cache/pip` to `jesse:jesse`. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

#### pip

I only have one problem, when I use `$ pip` I get this error:

```
The directory '/home/jesse/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned 
by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions 
and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want the -H flag.
```

#### .bashrc

Then when I load a terminal or just run `$ source ~/.bashrc`

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

#### Using

- 14.04 Desktop
- pip 6.0.6
- python 2.7.9

#### Tried

- Uninstall pip
- Removing ~/.cache/pip
- Reinstalling sudo apt-get python-pip
- Reinstalling easy_install pip
- Chown on ~/.cache/pip to `jesse:jesse`
- Deleting/Removing Python packages a lot, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would again purge python-pip and install it differently

```
 wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Then

```
 sudo python get-pip.py
```

And see if that works better for you.

**edit**

This route will get you newer than what in repo. You can also then update using

```
 pip install -U pip
```

Not sure if you can do that if installed with apt-get.

Comment: @JREAM Glad it worked for you!

Comment: No problem. This gets you newer than what in repo. You can also update using `pip install -U pip`